# AngularJS material nav bar to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I found a nice navigation bar demo in AngularJS material demo [site](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/navBar).
Specifically I want to transfer the nav bar demo to Angular Material.
Is that possible or not?

Comment: If you use https://material.angular.io/  with angular, yeah

Comment: Yes I use material.angular.io. Can you show me how and put it as an answer?

Comment: I couldn't find a navbar in material.angular.io. However, I use bootstraps https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview there are some examples